# Generating Combinations using Perl

Tags: perl, combinatorics

I need to write a Perl routine that will generate the n choose k combinations of a given set.  I don't need to count how many sets there are, I have to be able to print them out.  I'm pretty stumped.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want combinations without repetition, you can generate all binary numbers to length *k*, select those that have *n* 1's and apply them to the set in a fixed order: 0 means not selected, 1 means selected. To get a binary number, use `sprintf '%05b'`; to count 1's use `tr/1//`.

Comment: This looks encouraging!  Can you show me an example of how to use `sprintf '%05b'` and `tr/1//`?  They are both new to me.

Comment: @Schemer: See the documentation for [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) and [Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators). `sprintf` formats a string, and `%05b` is a 5-digit binary number with leading zeros. `tr` substitutes characters and returns the number of characters replaced or deleted, so `tr/1//` removes all the `1` characters and gives you the count of them.

Comment: Okay, I found sprintf by Googling.  But I couldn't find anything referencing `tr/1//`.

Comment: `tr/1//` does not remove anything unless you say `tr/1//d`. Quoteth perlop: "If the REPLACEMENTLIST is empty, the SEARCHLIST is replicated."

Comment: @mob: Yes, nothing is removed, but still counted.

Answer (score 5):

There's a module called [Math::Combinatorics](https://metacpan.org/module/Math%3a%3aCombinatorics) that produces combinations (nCr), permutations (nPr), and derangements of any set of things that you provide to it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that that module isn't installed on the machine I am working on and I can't install it myself.

Comment: @Schemer => that module does not use XS, and it does not have any non-core dependencies, so you can certainly use it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/755179/189416 for how.

Comment: Even if you can't install it, you can look at the source.